# Rxjs pipes - multiple operators in one pipe or multiple pipes?

Tags: rxjs, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I like the readability provided by

```
observable
  .pipe(operator1)
  .pipe(operator2)
  .pipe(operator3)
  .subscribe()
```

And it reminds me of a chain of thens for a promise.

**But** I know this is in every documentation example

```
observable
  .pipe(
    operator1,
    operator2,
    operator3
).subscribe()
```

Is there something lost in doing the first thing over the second? I am probably missing some crucial information here and maybe it's very obvious, actually. Thanks for the help.

Comment: What do you mean `lost`? The first example runs more code because you execute `pipe` multiple times. The outcome is the same.

Answer (score 5):

certainly they are equal and they have same result.

both of them is equal to

```
operator3(operator2(operator1(observable))).subscribe()
```